# Is it OK to ask questions about a certain product on Super User?

Tags: discussion, support

I am looking for a webcam and I wanted to know if I can ask for recommendations on superuser. Is this kind of thing allowed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Off-topic as per the **[Super User FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq)**:

> and it is not about …
>
> - videogames or consoles
> - websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress
> - electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer
> - ***a shopping or buying recommendation***

Please give the FAQ a read, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Generally no.

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

If you can rephrase your question in terms of *what you wish to accomplish* then perhaps.